# Is there any way to Know the Project is build in Eclipse or Android Studio?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

I Would like to know is there any way to know the project is build in `Eclipse` or `Android Studio`.Let's say I have one project how can i know this is build in `Eclipse` or `Android Studio`.

**Detail Description :**

I Download one apk form Play Store and I get the source code like below image format.

[image]

Any Help be Appreciated. I Search lot of thing but doesn't work me.

Comment: By project means just the apk file or the whole project containg source and layouts ?

Comment: @sharadchauhan by whole project including source and layouts.

Comment: is there any file named local.properties ?

Comment: @GodslaveAsad I think yes see the `ScreenShot`.

Comment: ok within this file you should get which IDE it used

Comment: @GodslaveAsad but `local.properties` doesn't give any information inside this file only one line is there `sdk.dir=C\:\\Users\\SoftEng\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\sdk`

Comment: Excuse me Ironman may you go to visit my quastion?
[enter link description here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39556473/6842709)

Answer (score 0):

The project from your screenshot is built in Android Studio. The highlighted `.iml` file is an IntelliJ IDEA project file and Android Studio is based on IntelliJ IDEA. Moreover it looks like a Gradle project - there is a `gradle` folder and `gradlew` script, which is usually another sign of using Android Studio.